# React - how to set same value in different states and make them work differently

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I am using state in React, and I have trouble with it.

In `componentWillMount`, I set same value in two state. Like below,

```
let value = this.props.value;
this.setState({
  a: value,
  b: value,
})
```

after setting state, I change `a` like below,

```
let a = this.state.a;
a = newValue;
this.setState({
  a,
)}
```

When I try to change state `a`, both `a` and `b` are changed together. Why does it happen?

Comment: How are you changing the state of `a`?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: To change state in react You can clean state or add new value. We often use that solution  this.state.a = value2; this.state.b = value3;

Comment: We need to see how you are setting the state of `a`

Comment: Is `this.props.value` an object that you are mutating later on?

Comment: Can you post the code which changes the state `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you made ***SetState*** for 2 state at once time. You should write :

```
//function a to setState for state a:
a = () =>{
     this.setState(a: this.props.value)
         }
//function b to setState for state b:
b = () =>{
     this.setState(b: this.props.value)
         }
```

So you can easy call to change State of a or b :)